# Hibernate used to work perfectly, but suddenly stopped working

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, swap, hibernate

So the hibernate functionality on my laptop use to work perfectly with Ubuntu. I would hibernate when switching to Windows and then thaw coming back. I literally never shutdown my Ubuntu partition for 8 months straight instead just using hibernate and thaw. But recently it stopped working all together.

Some details:

- I am using Ubuntu 16.04 xenial with kernel x86_64 Linux 4.13.0-36-generic
- When hibernating I would use `sudo systemctl hibernate`
- I have 16 GB of ram and I assigned 16 GB of swap space, though `swapon` tells me the swap space is 14.2 GB. Don't think that matters
- I recently did a `dist-upgrade` cause I was messing around with `xrpa` and `xvfb` and `xrandr`